# Кривой вывод строк

Tags: c#

Из-за вызова метода появляются лишние пропуски строк, не понимаю откуда они берутся)) Как убрать?Основной код

```
Console.Write("Введите размерность массива: ");
int dim = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[dim];
int[,] arr1 = new int[dim, dim];
int[][] arr2 = new int[dim][];



OneDimArray.SetArray(arr);
OneDimArray.FirstTask(arr);
OneDimArray.SecondTask(arr);

TwoDimArray.SetArray(arr1);
TwoDimArray.FirstTask(arr1);
TwoDimArray.SecondTask(arr1);
TwoDimArray.ThirdTask(arr1);
TwoDimArray.SetJuggedArray(arr2);
```

Методы для массива

```
public static void SetArray(int[,] arr)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Sqrt(arr.Length); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Math.Sqrt(arr.Length); j++)
        {
            arr[i,j] = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    DrawArray(arr);
}

public static void DrawArray(int[,] arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Sqrt(arr.Length); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Math.Sqrt(arr.Length); j++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,3}  ", arr[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

[image: как все выглядит]

Если убрать метод SetArray, то этого пропуска не будет

Comment: Этот код: `Console.WriteLine();` делает перевод строки. Уберите его в SetArray.

Comment: @AK спасибо, разобрался

Comment: Снял свой плюс с вопроса. Был нормально оформленный вопрос, а вы его удалили. Нехорошо. Не надо так делать. Делаю откат к исходной версии вопроса и закрываю правильно -- добавляю голос к "вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой"

Comment: @AK а как закрывать вопрос?

Comment: @AK человек пока не разобрался, что тут к чему.

Comment: @AK я просто форумчанин и мы всегда так делаем

Comment: So -- не форум, здесь немного другой формат и другие правила. Вопросы имеют ценность не только для конкретно вас, но часто -- и для тех, кто приходит из поиска. Конкретно такие вопросы, вызванные опечаткой не представляют ценности, но если удалять так варваски как вы сделали -- то вам придут и насуют минусов в репутацию. Оно вам надо? Потом вопросы не сможете задавать. Так что лучше удалить по-правильному и аккуратному.

Comment: У вас пока репутация не позволяет видеть механизм закрытия. So модерируется в основном самими пользователями, которым в зависимости от уровня репутации выдаются инструменты модерирования. Если хотите подробностей -- почитайте [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну вот когда я написал пояснения и откатил вопрос -- вернул плюс.

Comment: @AK спасибо вам )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `SetArray` уберите `Console.WriteLine();`

Comment: А, точно :) Случайно написал. Спасибо